# How to use LibTorrent for python to get information about the distribution?

Tags: python, libtorrent

I would like to get the distribution data BEFORE uploading. All there is is a magnet link or .torrent file. What do I need to do?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "distribution data"? Do you mean piece distribution? i.e. how many copies there are of every piece in the swarm.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is how the Internet translator translated it. I meant the size of the files. But I have already found the answer, I will leave the code in the answers if someone has such a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was incorrectly asked by me. I needed to find the size of all the files in the torrent. This is done using:

`handle = lt.add_magnet_uri(ses, url, params)`

`handle.status().total_wanted`